# How do I set a given bit from one bitmask to another in C?

Tags: c, bitmask

I want to set a given bit from one bitmask to another in C. This is the way I do it currently.

```
const int MASK_THIRD = (1<<2);

if (mask & MASK_THIRD) {
    mask_another |= MASK_THIRD;
} else {
    mask_another &= ~MASK_THIRD;
}
```

Is there a smarter way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

`mask_another ^= ((mask ^ mask_another) & MASK_THIRD);`

Which is in essence saying "if the bit is different, flip it". It requires one less operation which is why I figured it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I agree with this, but it is more difficult to understand :)

Comment: Agreed; XOR is so fun though!

Answer (score 1):

```
mask_another = (mask_another & (~MASK_THIRD)) | (mask & MASK_THIRD);
```

Reset bit in mask_another `(mask_another & (~MASK_THIRD))` and combine it with bit from mask `(mask & MASK_THIRD)`.